# WooCommerce: Add header to hooked in e-mail template information

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am currently using a plugin ( 
WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor) to add custom fields to the checkout page of WooCommerce and to also add this information to the e-mail. However the information is appended under the payment information like so:

[image]

In the best case I would like this to be above the Payment so under the general information. But I'd also be more than happy if it just gets an additional title with like "Bestelling Info" just right above the "Payment completed with Bancontact/Mister Cash ".

I assume this has to do with the following hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'wc_checkout_fields_add_custom_fields_to_emails', 10, 1 );
```

But I am not entirely sure how to properly hook into this to add the header or to move it above the payment information.

Does anyone know or could help me solving this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify with an image what sections are meant to be where?  Photoshop your current image and put the pieces where you want them to be if you can.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz I'm talking about the following area: https://imgur.com/oErxYiB and one option would be: https://imgur.com/pjzGgwD the other would be that it would be included to the main payment info like so: https://imgur.com/7KQM29L but also in the same style as the table. Is this possible at all? Any of the options that is?

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification I understand now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, perhaps you could provide me some insight on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm just checking out the plugin, give me a few minutes ;)

Comment: Sweet thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it's pretty straight forward, you can just hook into the action `woocommerce_email_order_meta` with a lower priority to the plugin's function so that then it will display a heading above the custom checkout fields.

```
function modify_woocommerce_email_order_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    echo '<h2>My Custom Order Fields Heading</h2>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'modify_woocommerce_email_order_meta', 9, 4 );
```